# Excel if statement produces `#NUM` unexpectedly

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I have searched and tried different things but I just can't seem to make this formula work. Background on what I am trying to achieve:

There are two dates in play here,

- Application date (cell B5) 'which everyone has

and

- Retirement date (cell F6) 'which only some people have, provided they have retired

If there is no retirement date, return nothing (works)

If the difference between `F6` and `B5` is greater than or equal to 15 months, display RTR>15 (works).

Otherwise display nothing even if the difference is negative (gives #NUM value in the cell when date difference is less than 15).

---

Formula I used:

```
=IF(F6="","",IF(DATEDIF(F6,B5,"m")>=15,"RTR>15",""))
```

It all works except when the difference between the two dates is less than 15 then it displays `#NUM` in the cell in red. So I am assuming I need to have a condition in there to handle negative values? but how can I fix this?

Comment: What's `DATEDIF`?

Comment: DATEDIF cannot return a negative.

Comment: try wrapping the DATEDIF in ISERROR: `ISERROR(DATEDIF(F6,B5,"m")>=15,FALSE)`

Comment: @BruceWayne it is a non-published function used for compatibility: https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-datedif-function

Comment: @ScottCraner - Woah, I didn't know they had non-published functions...Thanks for clarifying that!